# Mouse settings reset from static electricity

Tags: windows, static-discharge, earbuds

I drag my feet on my floor, I hear static buildup/zapping sound in my earbuds and I get the device disconnected/connected system sounds from windows and all my mouse setting reset to factory defaults (scroll speed, pointer speed, etc)  If I open the mouse's control panel, everything returns to normal immediately.

I've tried all the combinations of moving the mouse to each of the USB ports, as well as plugging in my headphones into the back instead of the front panel.

Any other ideas on how can I keep from shocking my mobo through my ears each time I shift position?

Comment: I'd make sure you ground your pc using a grounded wall-outlet.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I disagree. This is not a duplicate of that topic.

Comment: @LPChip He's asking how to discharge himself before touching the computer.  Whether just touching it, or actually opening it, one discharges themselves in the same way.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Sorry, but where exactly do you see this? An answer may be similar, but he's not asking for this.

Comment: @LPChip "Any other ideas on how can I keep from shocking my mobo through my ears each time I shift position?" is equivalent to "how can I discharge static from my body before zapping myself when touching the computer". At least to me anyway.  Regardless, takes more than just my vote to close; also note the word "possible". ;)

Comment: Wear rubber soled shoes?